# Time comparison in JPQL for Oracle

Tags: oracle, jpa

I want to select last 15 minutes record from DB with JPQL, my Named Query is

```
@NamedQuery(
  name="Request.Select", 
  query="SELECT b FROM EVCRequest b  WHERE b.timein > :timein")
```

And I query like following

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Request.Select");
query.setParameter("timein", new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() - 900000));
```

But its not providing expected results

In database date format is

```
"dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss aa"
```

Comment: What's the type of the timein column in the database? How is the entity EVCRequest defined and mapped?

Comment: Also, what do you expect as a result, and what do you get instead. You leave us in the dark by not providing details.

Comment: I enable logs and format of timein is different from database. My question is how I format timein according to Db. I tried simpledateformat but jpql expect format in date class but simpledateformat provide in string

Comment: The logs show how Java formats a Timestamp by default. The JDBC driver doesn't translate the Timestamp to a String. It uses its internal milliseconds value. The problem you have is not related to date formats. But since you don't want to say which problem you have, it's hard to say how you could solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved issue by applying native query like following

SELECT * FROM EVCRequest b  WHERE b.timein > sysdate-15/1440

Regards,